# Calling bean functions from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, javabeans

I have the following bean method signatures:

```
public String foo();  
public List<String> getList(String bar);  
public String getName(String baz);
```

The following works for me:

```
$("#div_id").append('<%= beanId.foo() %>');
```

The following is what I would like to do, but is a little more complex though, and I can't get it to work.

```
var list = '<%= beanId.getList("bar") %>';  
for ( var i in list ) {  
  $("#div_id").append('<%= beanId.getName('list[i]') %>');
}
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#div_id").append('<%= beanId.foo() %>');
```

works because the jsp-stuff is parsed on the server while creating the website, so you have the resulting code in you string.

```
$("#div_id").append('<%= beanId.getName('list[i]') %>');
```

this can't work because your javascript-variable is just known on the client-side *after* the sever has created the page. do what you want on server-side or use ajax instead.

Comment: Yes, I basically have to interact using get requests then. I've since changed the code accordingly. Thanks.